Non-English German Website Indexation Issue On Google
We are having issues in indexing one of our non-english store. Here is the timeline of events:
Event 1: Back 2022, we mistakenly made the website in english and english URLs got indexed
Event 2: We created the non-english URLs and permanently redirected english URLS to non-english URLs
Event 3: English URLS were deindexed and non-english URLs were crawled but indexed to some extent.
Event 4: We migrated the platform from custom to Shopify and relaunched the website. The new website is not being indexed. The problem is:
a- Majority of the pages are crawled but not indexed
b- Somehow old pages are also being crawled with 404 error (Not present in sitemap or being referred internally / externally)
We have open 20 stores on shopify in English and one in DE. All English stores has been indexed and there aren't any issues with them. Only issue with the DE website.
The Homepage is indexed only for DE.
We have already
1- Submitted sitemap GSC
2- Checked Robot.txt
3- Checked Indexability with URL inspection tool from GSC and everything seems fine
4- Implemented hreflang
Are there any SEOs who can help us with this indexing?
Details

How long have you been waiting on it to be indexed?
Probably not this causing the issue, but https://technicalseo.com/tools/hreflang/ shows that you are lacking region independent links in your hreflang tags.  For how to fix, see: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/125334/hreflang-region-targeting-multiple-regions-displaying-in-serps

I have been waiting for six months. I have added x-default in hreflang for regional independent link while setting up the website. We have 20+ stores on Shopify and all of them are indexed apart from DE store.
